# Shortest space-like path

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, variational-principle, geodesics

I consider the geometry around a massive homogeneous static spherical object (for example, a neutron star)

This system is static, so I am not interested in the space-time distance between two events.

I am interested in the spatial distance (without the influence of time) and the shortest path between two points?

Questions:

1. If a light source was turned on at point A, did the ray of light that first reaches point B has traveled along the shortest path? ( [Fermat's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle) )
2. Is the (null geodesic) path of the ray of light the (locally) shortest path between a two points?

The null geodesic is defined as ${g_{\mu\nu}} \frac {dx^{\mu}} {ds} \frac {dx^{\nu}} {ds}=0 $.

Can I remove time $\mu =0, \nu =0$ in my static (pure space-like) geometry in order to get non-zero distance?

$$ d(A,B)=L=\int_P \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}} \,ds$$

3. Is the length of that path the spatial distance between those two points?

Comment: Relativity modifies Fermat's principle. It is no longer shortest time, it is a null geodesic. You should be using an observer's measurement of how much time has passed between emission and absorption as the time, and hence the distance. It is then clear that the time and the distance is observer dependent, as it should be.

Comment: There is static light source in point A and static observer in point B. The first light ray that comes to observer has traveled by shortest path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) In the general theory light always travels along the null path, so light travelling from point A to point B indeed travels along the shortest distance between the two points, namely the path with arc length equal to zero.
2.) If you examine the non-temporal cross section you will find a non-zero distance for the path between the two points, and the path will be identical to the shortest path intrinsic to the, in general, non-Euclidean geometry of the space.
3.) Yes. For example, in the 1+1 dimensional case light will travel along the null line from A to B. If you project the world line onto the x-axis you have a curve that is a straight line connecting the two points. In a 2+1 dimensional example where the 2 dimensional space is a two sphere, you will have a path corresponding to a portion of the great circle connecting the two points; like drawing a line connecting two points on a globe. In each case the path has non-zero length and is a geodesic for the indicated geometry.

Comment: Light traveling at constant speed for a local observer. But is there any experiment proving that light sowing down going into stronger gravitational field e.g approaching the event horizon ?

Comment: So far as I am aware the basic postulate of relativity is that the speed of light in a vacuum is constant, however, there is the notable effect of gravitational redshift and blueshift for light travelling in a gravitational field, i.e. light falling into a black hole should be blue-shifted.